# Flutter build apk --release failed

Tags: android, flutter, apk

My application **worked well** on emulator or real device if I run the app by IDE.

Now I want to build apk release version by command:

```
flutter clean 
flutter build apk --release
```

Run the output apk file, it's always error:

> *The APK failed to install. Error: Could not parse error string*

[image]

Please help me to build correct release apk file

**Flutter version:**

```
Flutter 1.17.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f7a6a7906b (8 days ago) • 2020-05-12 18:39:00 -0700
Engine • revision 6bc433c6b6
Tools • Dart 2.8.2
```

Although I tried to configure release version in build.gradle as below:

This action already worked well for previous apps (now it is not).

**android\app\build.gradle**

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
-----android area---------
lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
...........
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
-----android area---------
```

How can I fix the problem ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If output apk means app-release.apk(because it should be that), you try to uninstall the app from your device then install again.

Comment: @Lunedor I tried the file already. still failed. thanks!